# How can I learn the top-level design of DefaultConfig in rocket-chip?

Tags: rocket-chip

I'm new to rocket-chip generator and I want to learn the top-level design of the default Rocket Chip instance (the one defined by DefaultConfig) before extend my own top-level design. For example, how many tiles does it have? What cores are in each of the tiles?

How can I get started? Read the codes in `rocket-chip\src\main\scala`?
Or is there any document offers some information about the Rocket Chip instance of the DefaultConfig?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions that ask "where do I start?" or "what can I do" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. Give a good read over [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your post with a specific problem you have - ideally presenting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to replicate it and people will be very glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking in `src/main/scala/system/config.scala`, you can find a class called `Default config`, then track that you can get all the configurations.